# Calculating the mode of an array containing hex values?

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I am programming in C#.

I've been experimenting with some code that calculates the mode of an array containing integers. i.e given `{5,6,2,1,5}` the mode is 5.

My questions is, can this be done with hex values?

For example, lets say I had the following array:

```
unsigned char HEXVALUES[ ] = {0x66, 0x60, 0xe7, 0xf0, 0x66};
```

How could I go about writing a program that tells me that 0x66 is the mode?

I've thought about converting them to decimal values and finding the mode that way, but it seems inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: hex number like 0x66 are integers and will give same results as decimal.  Bot hex and decimal are stored in memory as binary are read/write to strings using the specified format in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal value is just a representation of numeric value. E.g. these all are representations of same decimal value 102:

- 66 (Hex)
- 102 (Dec)
- 01100110 (Bin)

So just create array of integer values written in Hexadecimal format and make your calculations like with any other integer values:

```
var array = new[] { 0x66, 0x60, 0xe7, 0xf0, 0x66 };
var mode = array.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First().Key;
Console.WriteLine($"{mode:X}"); // output int as hex
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the mode of any collection is

```
theCollection
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
  .First()
```

Answer (score 0):

"Hex numbers" are the same thing as integers.  The difference is the way they are represented visually (in code, and when converted to strings).  In binary they are exactly the same.

So whatever code you used before on

```
unsigned char[] list = new char[]{5,6,2,1,5};
FindMode(list);
```

will work identically with

```
unsigned char[] list = new char[]{0x66, 0x60, 0xe7, 0xf0, 0x66};
FindMode(list);
```